# How should I test this method with JUNIT and Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, junit4

I'm new to Junit and Mockito unit testing. I need to unit test the method "processFiles(final File folder)"

When I run the test I get a NullPointerException at "if (!this.studentService.isFileOk(data))".

Can you help me to how I should be testing this method properly. Thanks a lot in advance.

This is a part of the code from the processFiles method:

```
@Stateless
public class ListFilesService{
 
  @EJB
  private transient StudentService studentService;
 
 public void processFiles(final File folder)
    {
        File[] fileNames = folder.listFiles();
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        
        try
        {
                    List<String> l = readContent(file);
                    l.forEach(i -> lines.add(i));

            String[] data = lines.get(0).trim().split(";");
            if (!this.studentService.isFileOk(data))
            {
                LOG.warning(String.format("File not valid"));
            }
            else
            {
                studentService.storeStudents(lines);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to test my processFile method

```
 

public class TestCases
{
 
 
    @Mock
    ListFilesService listFilesService;
    
    @Mock
    public StudentService studentService;

    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();
 
 
 @Test
    public void testWrite2() throws IOException
    {

        final File tempFile1 = temporaryFolder.newFile("tempFile.txt");
        final File tempFile2 = temporaryFolder.newFile("tempFile2.txt");

        String[] data = {"LastName", "FirstName", "Age"};


        listFilesService = new ListFilesService();
        studentService = Mockito.mock(StudentService.class);
        when(studentService.isFileOk(eq(data))).thenReturn(true);


        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(tempFile1, "LastName;FirstName;Age" +
                "\nxxx1;nnnn1;15", "UTF-8");
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(tempFile2, "LastName;FirstName;Age" +
                "\nxxx2;nnnn2;19", "UTF-8");


        listFilesService.processFiles(temporaryFolder.getRoot());

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the `ListFilesService` object by hand, not letting Mockito inject the mocks (specifically - `studentService`):

```
listFilesService = new ListFilesService();
```

When creating the object like this, the field `studentService` remains null, because it is not initialized in any way and it causes the application to fail with `NullPointerException`.

What you probably want to do is start your test class like this:

```
@Mock
private StudentService studentService;
@InjectMocks
private ListFilesService listFilesService;
```

and then call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` (read more [here](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.28/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html)).

Mocks initialization should be done before the test runs, so it's best to use a set up method with `@Before` annotation (read more [here](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Before.html)).

Remember to use the `listFilesService` field in your test and not create the object by `new`!